# Your request is prohibited because the request is on loopback from external IP

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Getting this error when trying to save entity in  local dynamodb ,i am running my application also locally .My all request are routed through a proxy which i can't disable due to organisation policy .Is there any way to avoid this error ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamoPost", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public TxnClass testPost(@RequestBody TxnClass input) {
        TxnClass response = txnInfoRepository.save(input);
        System.out.println("saved successfully");
        return response;
    }
```

error :-

> om.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
> at [Source: (byte[])"Request on loopback from external IP

## Request on loopback from external IP

---

**Description: Your request is prohibited because the request is on loopback from external IP.**

---

Comment: I was getting this erro when i was trying to connect to local dynamodb through proxy . We can get over this error by bypassing localhost from proxy or start using aws dynamodb instead of local dynamodb .